# Jade: how can I pass a random variable into included template?

Tags: javascript, html, pug

I have a jade template ('main page'), and a reusable template ('product template').
'product template' has to display dynamic data is used in many other pages, so it has to be unified and not dependable on variable names.

```
// main page
... (some code) ...

- var outerObj = [
  { title: '...', price: '...', description: '' },
  { title: '...', price: '...', description: '' },
  { title: '...', price: '...', description: '' }
];

// product temptate

.product
  .product__title=outerObj.title
  .product__price=outerObj.price
  .product__description=outerObj.description
```

**How can Include 'product template' and pass parameters in loop? (somewhat like this)**

```
// example of regular usage of 'product template':
- for (var i = 0; i < outerObj.length; i++)
  // pass only outerObj[i]
  include ./path/to/product-template.jade'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than doing an `include` inside a loop, you probably want to use a [mixin](http://jade-lang.com/reference/mixins/) which is like a function.

Something like this:

```
mixin makeProduct(product)
  .product
    .product__title=product.title
    .product__price=product.price
    .product__description=product.description

each product in outerObj
  +makeProduct(product)
```